# How can I pass the product image to stripe checkout page?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, stripe-payments

I successfully set the stripe in next.js. the problem is when I am redirected to the payment page, I do not get the image of the item. this is how it looks

[image]

I want to pass image to payment page. this is the handling the payment function:

```
const bookingRoom = async (id, pricePerNight) => {  
  try {
    // ...............

    // get this session
    const { data } = await axios.get(link, { params: { amount } });
    // loading stripe
    const stripe = await loadStripe();
    stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId: data.id });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};
```

I thought I should be able to pass through `redirectToCheckout({options})` so I checked the [docs here](https://stripe.com/docs/js/deprecated/redirect_to_checkout) but the only related options were

```
 lineItems: [room]  or items:[room]
```

Using both give me similar error:

> Invalid stripe.redirectToCheckout parameter: lineItems.0._id is not an
> accepted parameter.

Comment: Since there's a broken image icon being presented, it's quite clear that there's something wrong with the URL provided for the corresponding Product. Without knowing the image URL (and probably how you've passed in the image URL when creating the Checkout Session / Product), there's no way to troubleshoot. I suggest you reach out to Stripe Support who would probably have a way to check those details on your account.

Comment: For context, you can include an image when creating the Product. Via either https://stripe.com/docs/api/products/object#product_object-images, or https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-line_items-price_data-product_data-images

Comment: Hi, i know this is an old question and RedirectToCheckout is deprecated, but how did you get the title in the top left to show "Selling"?

Mine only shows "Mthly Dues" as some default title. Desperately trying to change this.